# How to get informations from two different form in Symfony2 and save them?

Tags: symfony

Actually, I have a form with an input to persist an entity. I want to create another form somewhere else with more information and I want to save everything from the submit which is in the first form. I can't include the second inputs in the same form, because this is not the same view. What's the best way to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds difficult.

Have I understood this right:

You have on entity with some required information and some nullable, additional information.

Now there are two forms one which creates the entity with the required information and you than want to update the form with the additionals.

Is this correct?

I would try two things:

1. Default
   You create one FormType with all the fields and have two views which only render the required fields (for this don't use form_rest).
   Than do the form handling like descriped in the docs.
   It could be that this doesn't work with the validation.
2. Use FormModels
   Under Form/Model/FormModelClass you have the two classes which only have the attributes the one form requires. The Form component interacts with them and maps all attributes to this models. When the form is submitted successfullly and valid you can manuelly map the attributes back to your orginal entity and persist it